# fonts not showing up in iframe in firefox

Tags: html, iframe, fonts

I have page with an iframe. Iframe content comes from other domain, but I have one css file that is included in `head` in that domain so both has same style, and it is. except for headlines `h1` with special font. It is shown properly in Chrome, Opera, IE and Safari, but not in Firefox :( It falls back to Arial.

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'TheSansLight';
     src: url('ABSOLUTEPATH/fonts/TheSans_TT3_.eot?iefix') format('ie9-skip-eot'),
           url('ABSOLUTEPATH/fonts/TheSans_TT3_.woff') format('woff'),
           url('ABSOLUTEPATH/fonts/TheSans_TT3_.svg#TheSans_TT3_') format('svg');
}
```

and later in css

```
font-family: "TheSansLight", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
```

Does enyone has any idea why firefox would not render font inside iframe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firefox has a cross-domain policy for @font-face which blocks them unless specifically allowed on the remote host. Google turns up any number of tutorials for working around it with Apache config, such as this one:

http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/07/fixing-firefox-font-face-cross-domain_25.html

Comment: thanks, mate. it looks like its solution indeed. Just wish I wouldnt have to bother other server administrator with such requests :(